# chrome wont install

Tags: installation, google-chrome

so i am trying the ubuntu thing out right i finally got it up and running but i hate firefox and love chrome but i tried installing it like it said and this is what was said

```
christina@owner-laptop:~$ $cd/tmp
bash: /tmp: Is a directory
christina@owner-laptop:~$ $ wget http://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

$: command not found
christina@owner-laptop:~$ $sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
christina@owner-laptop:~$
```

i have been getting that message alot  with anything i do with the sources.list so if anyones got an idea

Comment: the $ sign shouldn't be in the command, it's a sign some people use to tell you "nothing more is needed" or such. Why do you need chrome? Why not use chromium? Where did you get the instructions from?

Comment: According to your error you donot have the `sudo` privilege which is required for installation. Basically, if you are the only user in ubuntu, try `sudo -i` and see if you can get into `root` and try `dpkg` command.

Answer (score 4):

I would add the Google Chrome Repository so I get updates on chrome and not just this version.

Add the Repository:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub |
   sudo apt-key add -
```

setup the repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Update the software sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally install Google Chrome with:

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

[Soruce.](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Comment: I replace "PPA" with "Repository". PPAs are hosted at Launchpad.net. This is not a PPA. If you look at your source link, they even say that "3rd Party Repository: Google Chrome".

Answer (score 2):

First of all: [download the correct package (32bit or 64bit .deb)](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/)
When download finished, open the package with the Ubuntu Software Center and install with it.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you could install Chromium, the open source <strike>version of Chrome</strike> project that Chrome is based off of. Has all the same features, and still syncs with cloud saved settings for the regular Chrome (I sync bookmarks/passwords between Chrome for Android and Chromium on Linux). And, there is no need to add a repository, it is already included. So to install, simply

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Chromium is not the open source version of Chrome. Chrome is the closed source version of chromium. Google Chrome is created out of the open source project Chromium. it's a difference...

Comment: That is an important distinction, and I wasn't aware. Thanks!